# Late-binding collection to overloaded method

Tags: c#, dynamic, polymorphism, late-binding

**Background**

I have code that receives some deserialized data of type *IProduct* but the implementing class is unknown at runtime. I'm supposed to pass this data to an overloaded method that accepts an instance of the implementing class.

This can be achieved by using a switch statement, but it will look clunky and would require alot of code. I've solved this by using late-binding and runtime compilation for single entities but I'm unable to figure out how to do this for collections.

**Solving the problem for single entities**

If I have an object of type IProduct and want to pass this to the correct overloaded method that accepts an implementing class like Toy, Food, Car or something else. How do I achieve this without creating a big switch statement?

Given the following methods and interface:

```
public interface IProduct
{
     string Name { get;}
     double Price { get;}
}

public void Store(Apple apple);
public void Store(Toy toy);
public void Store(Car car);
```

With the switch statement it would look something like this:

```
IProduct product = new Apple();

switch (product)
{
    case Apple apple:
        Store(apple);
        break;
    case Toy toy:
        Store(toy);
        break;
    case Car car:
        Store(car);
        break;
}
```

I've managed to reduce this to the following using late-binding and runtime compilation.

```
IProduct product = new Apple();

Store((dynamic)product);
```

**Question**

However, I've not been able to figure out how to do late-binding in a similar fashion when it comes to collections.

Given the following methods:

```
public static void Store(ICollection<Apple> apples);
public static void Store(ICollection<Toy> toys);
public static void Store(ICollection<Car> cars);
```

How do I pass this:

```
ICollection<IProduct> products = new List<IProduct>() { new Apple()};
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing without using alot of magical code?

Comment: You don't, well, not without some hacking around. Fundamentally you are violating SOLID principles. If you have a list of apples then use a list of apples. If you have a list of products, then treat each item as a product.

Comment: This is ofcourse a dumbed-down example. I'm interested in a solution to this problem or an explanation to why it is not possible.

Just out of interest, how do you conclude that this is violating SOLID when I've only provided DTOs and an interface, which of the SOLID principles are violated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where these `Store` methods of yours are located. but something like this implementation is what seemed to me as the correct way to do things:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get;}
    double Price { get;}

    void Store(IProduct product);
}

public class Apple : IProduct
{
    public Apple(string name, double price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public double Price { get; }

    public void Store(IProduct product)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Toy : IProduct
{
    public Toy(string name, double price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public double Price { get; }

    public void Store(IProduct product)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Playground
{
    void Test()
    {
        IProduct apple = new Apple("apple", 11);
        ICollection<IProduct> apples = new List<IProduct>() { new Apple("apple", 230)};
        apple.Store(apple);
        IProduct toy = new Toy("toy", 11);
        ICollection<IProduct> toys = new List<IProduct>() { new Toy("toy", 230)};
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Siavash, thank you for trying to solve the problem. Doesn't this solution require a big switch statement like the one I showed above when solving the issue for single entities?

Comment: @Lillem4n I assume not, because the idea here is to move the implementation to concrete classes rather than some other arbitrary place.